# How to get Button Value into jQuery when using KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, knockout.js

My html:

```html
<button data-bind="attr: { value: URLPath }" type="submit">Download</button>
```

KnockoutJS jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qc84yyjp/

jQuery code:

```
$("Button[type=submit]").click(function () {
   var value =$(input).attr("data-bind");
   $.post('fs.php', 'val=' + $(this)+value, function (data) {
     alert("sagar");
   });
});
```

Live working example just need to pass button value into jQuery script can be found here:

https://oceanmovies.in/sagar/

Comment: If you are using knockout, why aren't you using knockout's own [click](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) binding which can have access to any value within your viewmodel or current item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use knockout `click` binding and call the `$.post` inside the function which is triggered by the click event.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

> The click binding adds an event handler so that your chosen JavaScript function will be invoked when the associated DOM element is clicked. This is most commonly used with elements like button, input, and a, but actually works with any visible DOM element.

Here are few of your HTML which I took from your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc84yyjp/)

```
<div class="grid-100" data-bind="foreach: exampleData">
  <h2 data-bind="text: Name"></h2>
  <li class="topics"><span data-bind="text: Size">Size</span></li>
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.download" type="submit">Download</button>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.exampleData = ko.observableArray([]);
  ...
  self.download = function(data) {
    // data => will contain a single object from exampleData array above
    $.post(...);
  }
}
```